# How to closing the old window in java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When opening a new window using **java GUI** I want to close the old one or just redirecting the old window to the new one i tried

```
setVisible(false)
```

but it didn't work.

the whole ActionListener code:

```
public class Domainevent implements ActionListener{
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
    GUI gg = new GUI();
    DomainGUI ee = new DomainGUI();
    gg.dispose();
    ee.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ee.setTitle("Forbidden Domains");
    ee.setSize(700,500);
    ee.setLocation(350,100);
    ee.setResizable(false);
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the code ??

Comment: i edited the question and posted the code

Comment: What is the code in GUI ??? are you setVisible(true) first for this JForm???

Comment: You are creating a new object (`gg`) and calling `.dispose()` on that new object, that has no effect at all on the "old" window.

Comment: ooooh, you solved it man, how fool i'm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jframe action listener when your new window is activated or open use dispose() to terminate your old window
Dont use setVisible() at all
You can dispose the old one right there when you are to call the new window
Say make a call newwindo n=new newwindow(); oldwindow.dispose();
After calling the new window

Comment: i've tried that and it didn't work: just give a look at the edited code above

Comment: oye suppose that when you are to call the new window object matlab    newWindow nw=new newWindow(); nw.somemethod();
just after it you can use your setVisible(false) or setVisible(true)
you can send your code at juni1289@hotmail.com for further assistance dear

Comment: take care if you're disposing the window by calling the dispose method in the same frame class you want to close then this should be called by using 
      this.dispose();
use this operator for the purpose

Comment: i had already found a solution for that, i just calling dispose(); without using any object with it. just calling the new window then calling dispose();

Comment: I was saying the same thing brother lols anyhow nice to chat with you stay connected juni1289@hotmail.com

Comment: It will be my please if you will mark my answer useful pleaseee requesting you

Comment: i marked your answer as accepted but i can't give it a vote up coz i'm have less than 15 reputation

Comment: So nice of you dear may Allah bless you ameen thanks a lot